# Render PDF for Apex Page return "PDF failed to generate" when soql row is 0

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx, html

I'm having trouble trying to render PDF page when there no record return for SOQL but work perfectly fine if I add a record to the look-up field

I do have additional content besides this table if there no row just shows a blank table

---VFP---

```
<apex:page standardController="Transmittal__c" extensions="TransmittalDetailsController" renderAs="PDF" applyBodyTag="false">
<body>
<div style="page-break-before:always; width: 100%; height: 100%; font-size:18px;">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Media Content</th>
                    <th>Media Types</th>
                    <th>Container</th>
                    <th>Original Data</th>
                    <th>Reference</th>
                    <th>Returning</th>
                    <th>Date Returned</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!transmittalDetailsList}" var="i">             
                        <td>{!i.Country__c}</td>
                        <td>!i.Media_Content__c}</td>
                        <td>{!i.Media_Types__c}</td>
                        <td>{!i.Container__c}</td>
                        <td>{!i.Original_Data__c}</td>
                        <td>{!i.Reference__c}</td>
                        <td>{!if(i.Returning__c = True, 'Yes', 'No')}</td>
                        <td>{!i.Date_Returned__c}</td>
                    </apex:repeat>

                </tr>        
            </table>
<body>
</apex:page>
```

---APXC---

```
public class TransmittalDetailsController {
    public List<Transmittal_Details__c> transmittalDetailsList {get; set;}


    public TransmittalDetailsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        Transmittal__c thisRecord = (Transmittal__c)controller.getRecord();

        transmittalDetailsList = ([SELECT transmittal__c, country__c, media_content__c, media_types__c, container__c, reference__c, original_data__c, returning__c, date_returned__c from Transmittal_Details__c
                                 where transmittal__r.Id =: controller.getId()  AND Id != null LIMIT 1]);

    }
}
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect or desire here? If you have no rows, there's nothing for the page to render.

Comment: Not knowing the exact requirements - I suggest you to use the apex:outputpanel rendered= condition for your table and render only if you have soql result else show meaningful message instead of pdf failed to generate.

Comment: I do have additional content besides this table if there no row just show table as a blank

Answer (score 0):

By moving the `<tr>` tag to after `<apex:repeat>` seems to be working

```
        <apex:repeat value="{!transmittalDetailsList}" var="i">
            <tr>
                <td><apex:outputText>{!i.Country__c}</apex:outputText></td>
                <td><apex:outputText>{!i.Media_Content__c}</apex:outputText></td>
                <td><apex:outputText>{!i.Media_Types__c}</apex:outputText></td>
                <td><apex:outputText>{!i.Container__c}</apex:outputText></td>
                <td><apex:outputText>{!IF(i.Original_Data__c = True, 'Yes', 'No')}</apex:outputText></td>
                <td><apex:outputText>{!i.Reference__c}</apex:outputText></td>
                <td><apex:outputText>{!IF(i.Returning__c = True, 'Yes', 'No')}</apex:outputText></td> 
                <td><apex:outputText>{!i.Date_Returned__c}</apex:outputText></td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
```